# btrfs filesystem is read only

Tags: linux, arch-linux, btrfs

for the past few days, I have noticed that my computer will either be in read only mode immediately after boot or shortly there after. Below is the error shown in dmesg. I have posted the entire ouput of `dmesg | grep btrfs`

```
  [  109.322761] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 230 at fs/btrfs/extent-tree.c:3076 btrfs_run_delayed_refs+0x167/0x1b0 [btrfs]
[  109.322822]  pps_core lpc_ich sg crypto_user ip_tables x_tables btrfs xor zstd_decompress zstd_compress xxhash raid6_pq sr_mod sd_mod cdrom hid_generic usbhid hid mvsas libsas ahci scsi_transport_sas libahci ehci_pci xhci_pci libata xhci_hcd ehci_hcd crc32c_intel scsi_mod usbcore usb_common nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops drm agpgart nvidia(PO) ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler
[  109.322910] Workqueue: btrfs-extent-refs btrfs_extent_refs_helper [btrfs]
[  109.322945] RIP: 0010:btrfs_run_delayed_refs+0x167/0x1b0 [btrfs]
[  109.322989]  delayed_ref_async_start+0x8d/0xa0 [btrfs]
[  109.323014]  normal_work_helper+0x39/0x370 [btrfs]
[  109.323111] BTRFS: error (device sdb4) in btrfs_run_delayed_refs:3076: errno=-17 Object already exists
```

since the filesystem goes read only, that's all the error information I have. I ran btrfs check and the following is the output.

```
WARNING: filesystem mounted, continuing because of --force
Checking filesystem on /dev/sdb4
UUID: 3fdec1ea-351f-40c3-a75a-974279e1d0e7
checking extents
checking free space cache
there is no free space entry for 15187968-15192064
there is no free space entry for 15187968-20971520
cache appears valid but isn't 12582912
ERROR: errors found in free space cache
found 79941521408 bytes used, error(s) found
total csum bytes: 71290456
total tree bytes: 1052409856
total fs tree bytes: 905068544
total extent tree bytes: 58998784
btree space waste bytes: 181546084
file data blocks allocated: 285620469760
 referenced 77330452480
```

To be thorough, here is the partition map of the drive shown by fdisk

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F8B87DB6-4AB2-4090-9C36-93F4CD94C9B3

Device        Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      2048     411647     409600  200M EFI System
/dev/sdb2    411648    2508799    2097152    1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3   2508800   18982911   16474112  7.9G Linux swap
/dev/sdb4  18982912 3907028991 3888046080  1.8T Linux filesystem
```

Any help in resolving this problem would be appreciated. I have tried btrfs repair. That kept printing the same thing out for the 1 hour I ran it. It was saying something about checksums. I don't have the exact output because it was run on a live system.

Comment: "I have tried btrfs repair" -- do you mean `btrfs check --repair`?